# MYSQL insert new record in table 2 on Table 1 Update record

Tags: mysql, triggers, sql-update

Not sure how to achieve this, I have the following 2 Tables :

```
Table 1
ID         > TYPE INT ( Primary ID, auto increment )
notes      > TYPE VARCHAR 

TABLE 2 ID  > TYPE INT  
notes       > TYPE VARCHAR 
ETA         > TYPE VARCHAR 
InsertDate  > TYPE DATE
```

Table 2 is initially blank table. I currently have a query in PHP to update Table 1.notes on specific ID.

What I want is every time I issue an UPDATE to Table 1.notes I want Table 2 to have the the values of Table1.ID and Table1.notes to be inserted . No primary key is specified for Table2.ID. So everytime I issue an UPDATE to Table1.Notes Table 2 gets another new entry with those values. I want to capture historical notes for Table 1 Notes.

Im guessing a trigger is best for this? Not sure how to do it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A trigger seems like a good option here.  Consider the code snippet below as an example of what you might do for your requirement.  Note that I insert `NULL` as the `ETA` value, because you gave no information for what the newly inserted value of `ETA` should be.  For the `InsertDate`, I use the current date.

```
DELIMITER //

CREATE TRIGGER table1_after_update
AFTER UPDATE
   ON table1 FOR EACH ROW

BEGIN
   INSERT INTO table2 (notes, ETA, InsertDate)
   VALUES (NEW.notes, NULL, CURDATE())

END; //

DELIMITER ;
```